# A question about the ideals of a ring of power series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let $F$ a field and we consider the ring of power series $F[[x]]$. After proving that $F[[x]]$ is a P.I.D. and after proving that the ideals of $F[[x]]$ are of the form $(x^k)$ for $k\ge0$, why $F[x]\supset (x)\supset(x^2)$? Why $F[[x]]\ne (x)$ and $(x)\ne (x^2)$.

Thanks!

Comment: In general, for any integral domain, and any nonzero nonunit $x$,  $(x^{n+1})\subsetneq (x^n)$. For if not, $x^n=x^{n+1}r$ would imply $xr=1$ after cancellation, contradicting that $x$ isn't a unit.  But I think Matt's raw description of what each of the ideals $(x^n)$ is like makes it patently clear already for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x)$ is the ideal consisting of series with no constant term. Certainly there exist series with nonzero constant term, hence the inclusion is proper. Similarly, $(x^2)$ is the ideal of series with no constant or linear term. Since there exist series with constant terms, or with no constant term but a linear term, the inclusion is proper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, if it were $F[[x]]=(x)$ we would be asserting that in $F[[x]]$ every formal power series has costant term null, but this is absurd, because just take $1=1+0x+0x^2+\cdots$. Moreover, if it were $(x)=(x^2)$ we would asserting that in $(x)$ every formal series has linear term null, but this is absurd, in fact just take $x=0+1x+0x^2\cdots$. It's correct?

Comment: @Jack Sure , that works.